# How to make special characters from a file be interpreted?

Tags: bash, scripting

How do I translate common escape sequences in such file:

```
abc\n\t\x22def\x22\t123
```

into characters that are escaped:

```
abc
    "def"    123
```

in Linux (Debian and CentOS)?

Specifically, I mean:
`\n`,
`\t`,
`\r`,
`\\`,
`\'`,
`\"`,
`\0`,
`\o**`,
`\x**`.

I have a feeling that there should be easy way to do it without big regexes or involving C compiler. Maybe, some Perl oneliner can do it? Or some Bash command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `echo`:

```
# echo -e "abc\n\t\x22def\x22\t123"
echo -e "`cat file`"
```

Output:

```
abc
        "def"   123
```

Comment: I knew that there should be something really easy.

Comment: Note [backticks are deprecated](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete), so it is better to use `$(cat file)` instead.

Answer (score 2):

jotik's answer is perfectly fine. You can also use:

```
echo -e "$(< file)"
```

See:

```
$ echo -e "$(< file)"
abc
    "def"   123
```

From `man bash`:

> **Command Substitution**
>
> Command substitution allows the output of a command to replace the com
>   mand name.  There are two forms:
>
> ```
>           $(command)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
>           `command`
> ```
>
> Bash performs the expansion by executing command and replacing the
>   command substitution with the standard output of  the  command, with
>   any trailing newlines deleted.  Embedded newlines are not deleted, but
>   they may be removed during word splitting.
>
> **The command substitution `$(cat file)` can be replaced by the equivalent but faster `$(< file)`.**